# Логические операторы || vs &&

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему выводит в консоль 1,2,3,4?
В моем понимании, должны быть только 3 и 4 (первым срабатывает && где выполняется последний false(3). Далее на проверке || срабатывает последний true(4)). Что не так? Спасибо!!

```js
function zfalse(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
  return false;
}

function ztrue(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
  return true;
}

zfalse(1) || ztrue(2) && zfalse(3) || ztrue(4)
```

Comment: к чему относится скобка после `ztrue(4))` опечатка? или есть еще какие-то скобки?

Comment: так ты вызываешь функции, которые в начале отрабатывают и далее применяются операции И/ИЛИ

Comment: Скобка опечатка - удалил

Comment: "первым срабатывает &&" - откуда взялось вот это предположение?

Comment: Приоритет у && больше чем у ||, соответственно оно первым сработать должно

Comment: @Alex оно срабатывает для булевых операций, ок. Однако, чтобы операции совершились, для начала эти значения должны откуда-то взяться. Они, соответственно, берутся из функций. А значит они все должны выполниться, чтоб сравнить между собой

Comment: Да, в моем примере срабатывают все функции. Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выполняется все слева направо, если расставить скобки будет понятнее:

```
zfalse(1) || (ztrue(2) && zfalse(3)) || ztrue(4)
```

Условия разделенные 'ИЛИ'(||) будут проверяться, пока хотя бы одно из них не вернет true

Условия разделенные 'И'(&&) будут проверяться, пока хотя бы одно из них не вернет false

Т.е.

1. `zfalse(1)` - печатает 1, возвращает false, поэтому идет следующая проверка
2. `ztrue(2) && zfalse(3)`

   1. `ztrue(2)` - печатает 2, возвращает true, поэтому идет следующая проверка
   2. `zfalse(3)` - печатает 3, возвращает false, общее значение выражения - false
3. `ztrue(4)` - печатает 4, возвращает true, общее значение выражения - true

В итоге выполнились все функции, следовательно вывелись все числа.